# javascript remove li without removing ul?

Tags: javascript, html-lists, removechild

Is there any way to remove the li elements of a ul without also removing the ul? I can only seem to find this.

```
var element = document.getElementById('myList');
element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
```

But, this removes the ul. I'm hoping to be able to remove and append li elements on the fly without also having to createElement the ul every time I remove li elements. Just looking for a simpler way. Thanks for any help.

```
<div id="listView">
  <ul id="myList" class="myList-class">
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You have an `li` with `id="div"`?

Comment: @Jeffman Keeps the next developer guessing.

Comment: Sorry, was in a hurry. html posted.

Comment: Cough. So is it `div` or `myDiv`?

Comment: Wow, now that you actually posted your code, @Jeffman was right! Just so you know, giving a `ul` an id of `myDiv` is a _very_ bad idea. Even `myUL` isn't great, try to make it descriptive, not deliberately confusing.

Comment: omg! it's a id. no div.

Comment: `'#id'` looks pretty wrong, and doesn't match the HTML. Are you trying to mix jQuery into this?

Comment: Yeah. I agree on everything you guys are saying. The id's and class names should be better. They are not the real names. I just used placeholder names for the purpose of the question. The original post was bunk. Sorry for that.

Comment: The code you have now DOES target the `ul`, so not what you want. To remove an `li` you need a reference to it. You get that by id or index number in some sort of collection. The answers below work if you want _all_ the `li`s removed. If you want to target just one, you'll need to specify it more clearly, by index, content, attribute -- something.

Comment: I know this removes the ul. I don't want to do that. I want to remove all li elements within the ul, while preserving the ul. What about Justin's method? Is this a proper way to handle? It seems pretty straight-forward and direct.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can do something like this.

```
var myList = document.getElementById('myList');
myList.innerHTML = '';
```

If you are using jQuery

```
$('#myList').empty();
```

Both of these will remove EVERYTHING inside the list.

Answer (score 17):

This should do the trick:

```
var lis = document.querySelectorAll('#myList li');
for(var i=0; li=lis[i]; i++) {
    li.parentNode.removeChild(li);
}
```

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/krasimir/UhhuX/

Comment: This worked for me with one addition. Because I was only removing certain list objects, not all of them I had to add "i = i -1;" after the removeChild call to make sure the list and the i index stayed in sync.

Comment: I liked this answer because it only removes the `<li>` elements. If, for some reason, you have something else in your `<ul>`, that won't get wiped out.

Answer (score 9):

The reason it's removing the `ul` is because you have the `element` variable pointing to the `ul`. Your next line of code then moves up to the parent (`#listView`) and applies the `removechild` method with the `element` variable (which points to `ul` element) passed to it.

If you need to remove all the li elements then you can use:

```
document.getElementById('myList').innerHTML = '';
```

which will empty the `ul` completely. If you need to remove selected `li` elements then you can traverse from `#myList` to the particular child elements using something like:

```
var ulElem = document.getElementById('myList');

ulElem.removeChild(ulElem.childNodes[i])
```

where `i` is the index of the `li` you want to remove (0 for 1st, 1 for 2nd, etc.)

For reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.removeChild

Answer (score 1):

```
const li = document.querySelectorAll(".list-item-class");
for(let i = 0; i <= li.length; i++ ){
    l = li[i];
    l.remove();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as we have a first child - remove it. (which will be as long as we have even one member).

```
  const removeNodesFromList = () => {
    const nodes = document.querySelector('.ul-class-selector');
    while (nodes.firstChild) {
      nodes.removeChild(nodes.firstChild);
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let ol = document.querySelector("ol");

function addItem() {
  let lastIndex = ol.childElementCount;
  let li = document.createElement("li");
  li.dataset.index = lastIndex;
  let a = document.createElement("a");
  a.href = "#";
  a.innerHTML = " Remove";
  a.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let index = e.target.parentNode.dataset.index;
    removeItem(parseInt(index));
  })
  li.appendChild(a);
  ol.appendChild(li);
}

function removeItem(i) {
  let li = ol.children[parseInt(i)];
  ol.removeChild(li);
  for (let j = i; j < ol.childElementCount; j++) {
    let li = ol.children[j];
    li.dataset.index = j;
  }
}

addItem();
```

```html
<ol>
</ol>
<button onclick="addItem()">Add</button>
```

Comment: While your snippet may be useful, please re-read the question, the user asks how to remove all nodes contained in a `<ul>` element.

Answer (score 0):

The way I solve this problem is that.
I create the deletion feature within the creation function:

HTML

```
<body>
    <div class="myclass">
        <h1>TODO App</h1>
        <!-- user input -->
        <input class="user_input" type="mytext" name="mytext" placeholder="Enter text">
        <button class="mybutton">Add</button>
    </div>
    <div>
        <ul class="ul-container"></ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

JavaScript

```
function creation() {
    const userInput = document.querySelector(".user_input").value;
    const ulContianer = document.querySelector(".ul-container");

    console.log(userInput);
    if (userInput !== "") {
        let li = document.createElement("li");
        let test = document.createTextNode(userInput);
        li.append(test);
        li.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
            li.parentNode.removeChild(li);
        })
        ulContianer.appendChild(li);
        document.querySelector(".user_input").value = "";
    }
}
```

So after you create it. Once you click li element, it will gone.